# how to index into a numpy array using another array of the same size

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have an a numpy array `a` and another one `dex` of type int of the same shape.  I want to use `dex` to index into `a`. How do I do that?

```
a = np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)

array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

dex = np.zeros((2,5)).astype(np.int)
dex[:,1] =1

array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I was trying something like this, which didn't work,
`a[dex]=100`
and got `print(a)`

```
array([[100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
       [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]])
```

I actually want the result to be `print(a)`

```
array([[0, 100, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 100, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: I think you are trying to give `a[dex==1]=100`, This will give you the desired results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you give a[dex], you are trying to refer to all the items. When you give `a[dex==1]=100`, then it is checking for specific value of `dex` and assigning the value of `100` only if the condition is met.

```
a[dex==1]=100
```

will give you:

```
[[  0 100   2   3   4]
 [  5 100   7   8   9]]
```